# Simple Word Guessing Game

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii

```
bool guess(char c)
{
    if (guesses[c])
    {
       guesses[] = c;
       return true;
    }
    else if (c > ='a' && c <= 'z')
    {
       guesses[] = c;
       return false;
    }
}

bool guesses[255] = {};
```

I need to use this to see if the person has enter a char between a - z and if they haven't I return true else I will return false. either way I will also update guesses with the char. Right now I don't understand how to add char to the array, so that next time I check the it will be false and tell them it was already guessed. I understand this is using the ASCII table but beyond that I am lost. Could anyone explain why this won't work.

I currently get the error

> expected primary-expression before']'

but if I take bracket out I get

> incompatible type char to bool

which make sense but then how do I make it so where char c is will be mark true in the Boolean array

Comment: does this even compile to you? ***guesses[] = c;***

Comment: What does the array `bool guesses[255]` represent? What do you want to do when you write `guesses[] = c;`?

Comment: No, you are not answering me. I'm not asking the literal meaning of a line of code. I'm asking what the array represents. And you are not answering my second question for clarification either for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left your brackets empty, so you currently aren't providing an index:

```
guesses[c] = c;
```

But you also don't want to assign the `char` to `guesses`, you'd want to assign a `bool`:

```
guesses[c] = true;
```

That will compile* and fix your problem.
* Note you also have a syntax error with `> =`, which I assume was just a copy+paste issue from the editor to the question, but you should fix that also to be `>=`. Your function `guess` can also potentially not return (if neither the `if` or `else if` are true), which is undefined behaviour. You should ensure all control paths return a value, and you should make sure you compile at the highest warning level so you are warned about these things.

But not your design.

Since you're only dealing with characters a-z, you don't need to allocate all 255 elements like you do. You could simply minus the character to obtain the correct index:

```
bool guesses[26];

if (c >='a' && c <= 'z')
    guesses[c-'a'] = true;
```

Consider instead using a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), a container of unique elements, to track whether a character has been pressed:

```
#include <set>

std::set<char> guesses;

bool guess(char c)
{
    // Have we already inserted this character?
    if (guesses.find(c) != std::end(guesses))
    {
        // Character has already been guessed:
        std::cout << "This character has already been guessed";
        return true;
    }
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    {
        // Valid guess:
        guesses.insert(c);
        return false;
    }
}
```